# drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window error while using getch() in C

Tags: c

In C there is a error I'm facing 
that when ever I use `getch()` command in my code and run it either in codeblocks or the .exe file after everything is done and when the control goes to `getch()` command it shows an error pop up window saying

> Drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", a);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Using Code::Blocks 16.01.

Comment: Please read [ask], post image **ONLY** when it can't be post as text.

Comment: Can you add your code here? Even though it is visible in image.

Comment: What compilation options did you use?  The `getch()` function can't be used in some styles of Windows application.

Answer (score 2):

I researched, what I understood was that the command `getch` is deprecated and the command you can use to replace it is the `_getch`.

There is more information at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch

Answer (score 2):

Use `_getch()` instead of `getch()`:

```
#include<conio.h>
_getch();
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch

Comment: Duplicate answer of Morpheus Curriculum Vitæ.